# Why java code working in Intellij Idea, but not working JAR file after building artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

My code working well from Intellij Idea by clicking Run. But created JAR file (build artifact) doesn't run with JVM Launcher error: "A JNI error has occur, pls check your installation and try again".

Previously it's was OK with builded JAR, but recently I modified my code and made some improvements and added some external JAR files to my project (HtmlUnit, HttpClient, etc).

I suppose that problem with dependencies, but how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included whole error message. It may be either problem with dependencies (not present/found) or they signature (some java libraries are signed and the problems occurs when the archive is repacked).

I was able to fix the problem by:

1. Configure the archive for the project:
   [image]
   [image]
2. Choose second option: "Copy to the output directry and link via manifest"
   [image]
3. Build artifact
   [image]
   [image]
4. The artifact will be generated in the choosen directory. Also the dependencies will be copied next to it

[image]

You can enter into the directory from command line and run the app (or create a script):
[image]